# how to create rectangle button and disturb it horizintaly

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to create 4 buttons horizontaly with equal width and height.
Now I set width to 0dp and set weight = "1", this allow me disturb all buttons horizontaly with equal widht, but now I need set equal height of this elements and don't know how to do it.

Please, help me solve this.

Below my xml layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:id="@+id/lin_layout">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="VK"
                android:id="@+id/btn1" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ЮД"
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="KE"
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/contact_bg"
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:text="MI"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just supply a dp dimension value as the parent LinearLayout's height and set each Button's height to match_parent

Comment: I can't do this, because don't know which width on different device.

Answer (score 0):

But it depends on the height of the same thing, if you want the buttons to be all the same height with respect to the linear layout just set `android: layout_height = "match_parent"` and the buttons will be as high as the **linear layout**.

example

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="VK" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ЮД" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="KE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="MI" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, that height of button must be equal of it width. See image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is impossible to do what you're asking solely in xml, I'm afraid you will have to do it dynamically.

First of all change all the button's heights to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:id="@+id/lin_layout">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="VK"
            android:id="@+id/btn1" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ЮД"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="KE"
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/contact_bg"
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:text="MI"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And afterwards get the width of the `LinearLayout` and set it's height to 1/4th of it's width.

```
lin_layout.getLayoutParams().height = lin_layout.getLayoutParams().width / 4;
```

Comment: Notice op has set margins around the Buttons, so the width of the Buttons should be used as their heights instead of using a quarter of the screen width.